# Datetime object in DataFrame with just time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, object, indexing

This is the plain column

```
0       06:55:22
1       06:55:23
2       06:55:24
3       06:55:25
4       06:55:26
```

And the I would like to put that column in the index, the problem is when I try to use the method resample() I always get the same problem:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

I've been using this to change the Time column to

```
datetime dt['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dt['Time'],format).apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the `Time` column as your index of the dataframe.

```
In [1954]: df.set_index('Time')                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[1954]: 
          a
Time       
06:55:23  1
06:55:24  2
06:55:25  3
06:55:26  4
```

#### Update after OP's comment

If you don't have a `date` column, so pandas will attach a default date `1900-01-01` when you convert it to `datetime`. Like this:

```
In [1985]: pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')                                                                                                                                                    
Out[1985]: 
0   1900-01-01 06:55:23
1   1900-01-01 06:55:24
2   1900-01-01 06:55:25
3   1900-01-01 06:55:26
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot change the dtype:object to datetime of that column and the put the column as datetime in the index...

Comment: @renton Do you also have a `date` column? If not, I've provided a solution. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: No I don't have it, but i just need the time, I don't want the date... , is that possible, or the program always needs a date to make something as I want

Comment: If you don't give a date, it will add a default date. Please check the second part of my answer.

Comment: oook, so I have to create a date column I think, It's just one day so haha

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.